# Updating untracked data after rebase in git

Tags: git

I have a post-checkout hook that is supposed to update a `VERSION` file to make the current git version accessible to the build system. For various reasons, having the build system update the `VERSION` file itself would be complicated in our situation.

In general it works very nicely. Except when I do a git-rebase, the post-checkout hook only seems to get called after the new commits are added, not after the local commits are replayed. As a result, the `VERSION` file is wrong. There isn't a post-rebase hook from what I can tell, so I'm at a bit of a loss as to how to keep something like that up to date when rebasing. Thanks.

In case it matters, the command I use in the post-commit is

```
echo `git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD`-`git rev-parse --short HEAD` > `git rev-parse --show-toplevel`/VERSION
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you have a look at the [post-rewrite hook](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/githooks.html#_post_rewrite)? It looks like that’s exactly what you need:

> This hook is invoked by commands that rewrite commits (`git commit --amend`, `git-rebase`; currently `git-filter-branch` does not call it!).

Comment: I had missed that. Thanks. While the branch doesn't seem to have been updated when it is run (so `git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD`) I can probably extract that from the hashes of the old commit.

Comment: You get a list of rewritten SHAs on STDIN. Just take the old head and look for its new equivalent. Have a look at the docu I linked.